# Need to associate my domain name with amazon ec2 instance without elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am somewhat new to using Amazon EC2 instances and the only experience i have got is basically setting it up and using the same.

Now due to financials involved i don't want to go for any dedicated IP in my AWS account and as a result the public IP which is assigned to me keeps on changing. Can i assign the domain name which i own in such a scenario with my EC2 instance?

If yes, can anybody help me with the same or point me some resource which can guide me.

BR,

Anurag Jain

Comment: What service manages DNS for your domain? Does that go through Amazon or a third party (like Namecheap, Godaddy, etc)?

Comment: Third Party, godaddy...

Comment: *i don't want to go for any dedicated IP*  ... You do realize that if your instance I running all the time, there is no charge for an Elastic IP, and if not, it will only cost you $0.005 to leave the address allocated for each hour the instance isn't running.

Comment: Ok, let me check upon that possibility. However, is there any alternative which i can use without using the elastic IP stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the same methods DynDNS, Afraid (FreeDNS), or NoIP use for dynamic IPs. There are a lot of guides created that help you point a domain to your home IP. You want to adjust the TTL down, if possible.

I'm not sure who manages your DNS, though, so I'm not sure how to explain further.

Comment: Godaddy, can you now suggest me some steps to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are relatively new to aws EC2, you should have the first 12 months of use for free. 
Also, as long as you do not restart your instance, your public ip will remain the same.(750 hours free/month)

Comment: free tier does not suffice my need, hence cant opt that.